# Deleting a heap then dereferencing a pointer to that memory

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

This is code from an exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 13;
    int* ip = new int(n + 3);
    int* ip2 = ip;
    cout << *ip << endl;
    delete ip;
    cout << *ip2 << endl;
    cout << ip << tab << ip2 << endl;
}
```

When the space allocated to the int on the heap is deleted, I thought that dereferencing the pointer would give some sort of memory error. Instead, it returns 0.

Why is this?

Comment: Thanks for answers re: undefined behaviour.

Assuming the memory wasn't overwritten by another program, the delete function appears to write a null in the first word of the heap. Does this seem strange to you?

Comment: OK. I think I found the answer to the zeroing mystery: Stroustrup says "C++ explicitly allows an implementation of delete to zero out an lvalue operand, and I had hoped that implementations would do that, but that idea doesn't seem to have become popular with implementers." I tried doing a 'delete ip2' after 'delete ip' and this gives a double free error. I guess I can check the assembly to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dereferencing an invalid pointer leads to undefined results per spec. It's not guaranteed to fail.

*Usually (CPU/OS/compiler/... dependent)*, the compiler doesn't really care about it at all. It just gives what's currently at that memory address. For example, in x86 architecture, you just see an error only when the address is in a memory page that's not mapped to your process (or your process doesn't have permission to access that), thus an exception will be thrown by the CPU (protection fault) which the OS would handle appropriately (and probably, making your process fail). A trick is sometimes used to make accessing the address `0` always cause an access violation: The OS sets the read/write bits of the first page of the address space in the page table to 0 so that any access to that page will always generate an exception.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I'm missing something since no page fault is generated, BUT the dereferencing produces zero. Now if it was still pointing to the same area of memory, then you'd expect the old value to be there (assuming not over-written). I've run the program several times and pointer is not null so there's something else going on. This is gcc compiler on IA-32 arch.

Comment: bugmenot77: That's just a side note. I meant to say most C/C++ implementations don't really care and the error that you sometimes see is from OS/CPU, not the compiler. About your question, when you delete a pointer, the pointer itself is not set to zero automatically. The value of that memory location might be overwritten (you can't assume anything). Anyhow, NOTHING is guaranteed about this. You should not rely on an invalid pointer at all.

Comment: Also, it's common for debug builds to deliberately fill the memory with some values to aid debugging.

Comment: Thanks. It is the zero filling that is confusing me. I ran several iterations to see if it was ever non-zero to eliminate the overwriting scenario (didn't expect over-writes given this is a single user desktop machine with nothing else happening). What you said re: debug build makes sense. This isn't debug which is why it surprised me as if delete was overwriting with zeros, it would suggest performance implications. Anyway, it seems a mystery and perhaps only someone with knowledge of gcc, linux and x86 would know.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is undefined, and so what will happen is implementation and system dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing the `ip` pointer will return what happens to be at that memory location at that time.

It's returning 0 because that's what the four bytes at `ip` happen to encode to when cast as an integer.

dereferencing a pointer after it's been deleted is unpredictable. It might be zero, it might be something else if that memory has been reallocated elsewhere.

You're just lucky that it's 0 when you run your program.

Comment: _"Dereferencing the ip pointer will return what happens to be at that memory location at that time."_ You do not know that. The result is **undefined**. C++ is an abstraction, not a one-to-one mapping of physical machine instructions.

Comment: I literally wrote that in the next paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Further to Mehrdads answer, In gcc with glibc, the data structures representing the memory heap are stored in the block of memory returned, to save memory (i.e. its an intrusive list). So, when a block of memory is freed, it is added to the free list. My guess is that the 0 being written following the free indicates that this is the last element of the the free block list (the first pointer sized word of deallocated memory will contain the lists `next` pointer).

If you were to allocate and free more memory before dereferencing this block again, the value would change when a new item is added to the end of the free list. This is one way that library implementation decisions affect what happens during 'undefined' behaviour. In this case, the glibc developers have taken advantage of the fact that this behaviour is undefined to make their memory allocator more space efficient.

If you run your program under valgrind, it will catch these errors for you. In any case, always stay away from undefined behaviour, since it is very likely to be different on various platforms and even different builds on the same platform (e.g. debug vs release).